# How do you do this conditional situation with regular expression? 

Tags: php, javascript, regex, perl

1. Begins with alphanumeric `^[a-z0-9]`
2. Then followed by this optional dot `\.?`
3. If there is a dot, then it MUST be followed by 2 to 4 alphabets `[a-z]{2,4}`
4. It must be ends with an alphabet `[a-z]$`
5. It has to be a dot and only two dots max.

it's like domain names:

`yahoo.co.uk` or `yahoo.com`, but you cannot do this `yahoo.co.u` or this `yahoo.co.`, yes something like that.

Comment: You say "it's *like* domain names", but *is* it domain names? Because if so, I was wondering about the Unicode-ness.

Comment: it's not domain name, but it's like domains

Comment: #4 - does the first part need to end with [a-z] regardless of whether there is one or more \.[a-z] ?

Answer (score 7):

You can group the optional dot with the 2-4 characters that must follow it: `(\.[a-z]{2,4})`. That said, you will have either none, or up to two of these groups of dot + alphabetic characters `(\.[a-z]{2,4}){0,2}`.

The must end with `[a-z]` part, you can check with a positive lookbehind `(?<=[a-z])` giving this as the full regex:

```
^[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z]{2,4}){0,2}(?<=[a-z])$
```

This will work in Perl and PHP regexes (PCRE), but not in JavaScript, because it does not support lookbehind. In this specific case, you can work around that limitation.

If there is at least one dot, there's already a guarantee that it will end in `[a-z]`, because that test is in the group that the dot is a part of. If there is no dot, you need to force a `[a-z]` at the end. To do this you can turn the one-or-more quantifier (`+`) into a zero-or-more (`*`) and force the end to be an `[a-z]` when there are no "dot groups". When there are dot groups, you can keep the same pattern, but now with at least one mandatory dot.

```
^([a-z0-9]*[a-z]|[a-z0-9](+\.[a-z]{2,4}){1,2})$
```

Comment: Your regex without lookbehind will allow ".co.uk"

Comment: Thanks for your enlightenment.

Answer (score 5):

This checks for a string that begins with `[a-z][0-9]` and then contains one or two dots followed by 2/4 alphabets.  It works (in Python, at least) for the examples you provided (true for `yahoo.co.uk` and `yahoo.com`, false for `yahoo.co.u` and `yahoo.co.`)

```
^[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z]{2,4}){1,2}$
```

Edit - upon re-reading, I think you may want this instead:

```
^[a-z0-9]*([a-z0-9](\.[a-z]{2,4}){1,2}$|[a-z]$)
```

This will match strings (in addition to the above) that do not include dots but end with a letter, such as `yahoo`, but not `yahoo2`.

Comment: No: "Begins with alphanumeric".

Comment: Oh, right - I misread your comment somehow.  Thanks, should be fixed!

Comment: your last method works, `if(preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]*((\.[a-z]{2,4}){1,2}$|[a-z]$)/", "yahoo.com.au"))echo "ok";` prints out `ok` or `alert(/^[a-z0-9]*((\.[a-z]{2,4}){1,2}$|[a-z]$)/.test("yahoo.co.uk"));` the result is `true`. And I've tested with many conditions, so far so good. thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
^[a-z0-9](\.[a-z]{2,4}|.*[a-z]$)
```

Comment: `alert(/^[a-z0-9](\.[a-z]{2,4}|.*[a-z]$)/.test("yahoo.co.u"));` the result is `true`. I expect `false` :(

Comment: What are you talking about?? Under your requirements "yahoo.co.u" SHOULD PASS: it starts with alpha (y), there is not dot following (a), and ends with alpha! Also, you have CHANGED your question with point 5 (which STILL PASSES). Please remove the downvote!

Comment: the OP specifically states that `"yahoo.co.u"` should not match. And i don't think a downvote can be removed except in the first few minutes or after an edit. Change your answer to something useful and you might get lucky.

Comment: The downvote is not from Yoyo_c. It's mine. I usually downvote answers with nothing but code as I don't find them useful, especially in [tag:regex]. But more importantly, this does not meet the requirements. "If there is a dot, then it MUST be followed by 2 or 4 alphabets [a-z]{2,4}". That's why "yahoo.co.u" should not pass.

Answer (score -1):

```
^[a-z0-9](?=[^.]*\.[^.]+$|[^.]*\.[^.]\.[^.]+$)(\.(?=[a-z][a-z]){1,2}).*[a-z]$
```